# Copy corresponding dataframe column values to new dataframe with fixed column names python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, columnsorting

I have a data frame (df1) as shown below. The elements in the 1st column start repeating after a certain number but the corresponding 2nd column elements are unique

```
    0        1
0   A        Ok
1   B        1234
2   C        True
3   D        Yes
4   A        Ok
5   B        6789
6   C        False
7   D        No
```

I have created a new DataFrame(df2) with column names as the elements in the 1st column of df1 without repetition

```
column_names = df1[0].drop_duplicates()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
```

I want to copy the elements in the 2nd column of df1 under the column names in df2 as shown

```
    A     B       C      D
0   Ok   1234    True    Yes
1   Ok   6789    False   Yes
2   Ok   1567    False   N/A
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

group the repeating values in the first column with cumcount and then use that in the pivot.

```
# create a temp idx, which is cumcount of unique values in rows, and then use that with pivot
# finally reset index and drop the temporary created column

(df.assign(idx=df.groupby([0]).cumcount())
 .pivot(index='idx', columns=0, values=1)
 .reset_index()
 .drop(columns='idx')
 .sort_index(axis=1)
)
```

```
0    A     B       C     D
0   Ok  1234    True    Yes
1   Ok  6789    False   No
```

Alternately, i modified the provided data and here the order of the column is preserved

```
data = {0: {0: 'Z', 1: 'B', 2: 'X', 3: 'D', 4: 'Z', 5: 'B', 6: 'X', 7: 'D'},
        1: {0: 'Ok',  1: '1234',  2: 'True',  3: 'Yes',  4: 'Ok',  5: '6789',  6: 'False',  7: 'No'}}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

(df.assign(idx=df.groupby([0]).cumcount())
 .groupby(['idx',0],sort=False )[1].sum().unstack() 
 .reset_index()
 .drop(columns='idx')
)
```

```
     Z     B       X     D
0   Ok  1234    True    Yes
1   Ok  6789    False   No
```

Comment: Hello @Naveed. Thank You...This works for me with small changes...groupby([0]) , cloumns=0, values=1 ...without ' '.....But one thing is that the column names have been arranged in alphabetical order (ascending). Is there a possibility to just keep the column names in the order they appear in the df??

Comment: @PradyumnaTK, you can sort the columns as follows df.sort_index(axis=1)  the result I shared is how it was returned for me. i updated the solution as well. hope it helps!

Comment: No...My problem is that the column names have been sorted...I dont want them to be sorted...My ctual column names are not in alphebetical order...In the above question, i only gave the column names 'A,B,C,D' as examples....I dont want my column names to be sorted....I want them to be in the same order as they appear in the dataframe previously

Comment: @PradyumnaTK, added an alternate solution, with a modified dataframe to clearly see if column order is preserved. Hope it addresses your last concern. let me know